# Mode of a sum of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $S_n=\tau_1+\cdots+\tau_n$ be a sum of independent Bernoulli random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_i=1)=p_i$. Is it true that the mode of $S_n$ is either its mean rounded up or rounded down?

Comment: That would be rather surprising, given that there are plenty of values $p_i$ giving the same mean. Have you tried the lazy way to check it (computer simulations)?

Comment: Why does it have to be unimodal at all?

Comment: @RW It is strictly log-concave.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of Darroch's theorem: if a polynomial with positive coefficients has all of its roots real, then the mean and mode are distant by at most $1$. This applies here: $\prod (1-p_i + p_i x)$ is the Fourier transform, so the answer is yes. See Pitman's survey on log concave (aka strongly unimodal) distributions for a reference to Darroch's result.

Comment: Here's the reference. J Pitman. Probabilistic bounds on the coefficients of polynomials with only real zeros. J. Combin. Theory Ser. A, 77(2):279–303, 1997. Darroch's theorem appears somewhere in there; there is a paywall, and I can't get to it.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Here is the original paper by Darroch (open access): https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177703287

Comment: What is a mode?

Comment: @ChristianRemling for a discrete distribution it is a value that is taken on with maximal probability.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas OK; done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darroch's theorem  is the following. Let $p = \sum a_i x^i$ be a polynomial with positive coefficients, and suppose that all the roots of $p$ are real (hence negative or zero) [the corresponding distribution of coefficients is called PF, for *Polyà frequency*]. Then the mean of the distribution $(a_i)$ differs from the mode by less than $1$. [The theorem also gives a partial result on which of the two integers nearest the mean is the mode when the mean is not an integer; but in cases where I wanted to use it, it was just too crude.]

Here the polynomial whose distribution we are interested in is $\prod (1-p_i + p_i x)$, which obviously has only negative real roots. Hence the answer to the question is yes.

I became aware of Darroch's theorem from a preprint of J Pitman, eventually published, *Probabilistic bounds on the coefficients of polynomials with only real zeros,* J. Combin. Theory Ser. A, 77(2):279–303, 1997 (unfortunately behind an Elsivier paywall), although the preprint might be available somewhere. It contains lots of examples using Darroch's theorem. Fedja found Darroch's paper at projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177703287.